# How to use LazyPaginator together with RequestConfig and Table classes?

Tags: django-tables2

I want to visualize a big, indexed table - big enough for `count(*)` to be too slow for my use case. Here's my views.py code:

```
import django_tables2

from projectname.models import Growth

def dashboard(request):

    class StatisticsTable(django_tables2.Table):

        class Meta:
            model = Growth

    table = StatisticsTable(Growth.objects.all())
    django_tables2.RequestConfig(
            request
    ).configure(table)
    return render(request, "plain_table.html", {'table': table,
                                                'title': 'Growth dashboard',
                                                'search': None})
```

I was looking for examples on how to use `django_tables2.paginators.LazyPaginator` here and so far only found that I should pass it as a `paginate=` in `django_tables2.RequestConfig`, but I still get a regular paginator if I pass a reference to the class there. What's the proper use of this class in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RequestConfig(paginate={"paginator_class": LazyPaginator}).configure(table)
```